# Cannot return substring value angular typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

html

```
<p>
    <input type="text" maxlength="40" (input)="recipientReference = deleteSpacing(recipientReference)" [(ngModel)]="recipientReference" style="width: 30vw; padding: 5px;border: 1px solid;border-radius: 5px" />

</p>
```

ts

```
deleteSpacing(object){
        if(object == this.recipientReference){
          if(object.replace(/\s/g, "").length > 11){
            let phone = this.recipientReference.substring(0, 2);
            if (phone == "+6") {
              
              return object.replace(/\s/g, "").substring(2, 13);
            }
            return object.replace(/\s/g, "").substring(0, 11);
          }
          else {
            return object.replace(/\s/g, "");
          }
        } else {
          return object.replace(/\s/g, "");
        }
    return object;
  }
```

return object.replace(/\s/g, "").substring(0, 11);
willn't return substring but return whole string. Therefor,
return object.replace(/\s/g, "").substring(0, 10);
will return substring.

How can i get the substring with 11 characters?

Comment: `object.replace(/\s/g, "").substring(0, 11)` will get you 11 characters, it starts at index 0 (inclusive) and end at index 11 (not inclusive), which is exactly 11 characters (assuming your string is long enough). Checkout the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) documentation to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

First you can remove the space using regEx then use substring() to get the subset

```
 var str = "How can i get the substring with 11 characters";
  var res = str.replace(/\s/g, '').substring(0, 11);
```